# Enter many numbers using raw_input()

Tags: python

In my program, there are two variables `freq` and `flux`, which values I want to apply using `raw_input()` or other similar python functions. My input values of `freq` and `flux` are not fix. For instance, in some case there are 3 `freq` and 3 `flux` values, and in some case there are 6 `freq` and 6 `flux` values. So how can I write a common program which takes `freq` and `flux` values which I entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could enter arbitrary values separated by spaces with

```
freq = raw_input("Enter freq values separated by spaces ").strip().split(" ")
flux = raw_input("Enter flux values separated by spaces ").strip().split(" ")

print freq, flux
```

In this code `raw_input()` returns entered string, `strip()` removes leading and ending spaces from this string and `split(" ")` split string by spaces and returns a `list`. Results

```
In [72]: freq = raw_input("Enter freq values separated by spaces ").strip().split(" ")

Enter freq values separated by spaces 1 2 3 4

In [73]: flux = raw_input("Enter flux values separated by spaces ").strip().split(" ")

Enter flux values separated by spaces 2 3 4 5 6

In [74]: print freq, flux
['1', '2', '3', '4'] ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

If you want to convert results to float you could use `map()` function

```
flux = map(float, raw_input("Enter flux values separated by spaces ").strip().split(" "))
```